# jquery slidetoggle not working with div, ul, and display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle a menu dropdown with slideToggle but I can't seem to get it working. My goal is to click on "Attack" and have the list of attack options show. Here is my code.

```
<div class="turn-option" id="attack">
    <h2>Attack</h2>
    <div class="attack-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="attack-type">Attack 1</li>
            <li class="attack-type">Attack 2</li>
            <li class="attack-type">Attack 3</li>
            <li class="attack-type">Attack 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


.attack-menu {
    display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#attack").click(function() {
        $(".attack-menu").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working.. Perhaps something else in your code is causing issues.. https://jsfiddle.net/LLhy8L4n/

Comment: @christian Check your console for errors. Maybe your jquery library is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Your jquery library might be causing the error. Try including this script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Refer this link : [Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-slidetoggle.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added the line you included but still get this in the console:


script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:2

Comment: Found the issue, I had my jquery line AFTER my js filepath. Thank you!